# Asynchronous array problems

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

Near the end of the look where you see console.log(authors), the array is constantly overwriting itself. The async part of this loop is usually outside the loop. I did this to debug the reason why I get a big array full of the same username, rather than an array full of a series of different usernames. This is the code I have:

```
while (i >= 0) {
  var search = User.find({'twitter.id' : collected[i].author});

  search.limit(1);
  searches.push(function(cb) {
    search.exec(function (err, hold){
      if (err) cb(err, null);
      else {
        cb(null, hold[0].twitter.username);
      }
    });
  });
  i = i - 1;

  async.parallel(searches, function( err, authors) {
    if ( err ) return console.error( err );
    else {
      console.log(authors);
    }
  });
}
```

These are the results I get:

[image: results]

It's been a long day, I'm not quite seeing where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't your logic be in the callback function of `User.find`?  As in `User.find({'twitter.id':collected[i].author}, function(user) { /* logic */ });`

Comment: Shouldn't `async.parallel` be outside the while loop?

Comment: @epascarello: *"The async part of this loop is usually outside the loop. I did this to debug the reason"*

Comment: @nathanleung I'm prepared the query beforehand, it still works the same way in execution.

Comment: @epascarello It is in practice, but like described, I get given an array full of the same username, rather than a varied array of names. I was debugging here.

Comment: Sounds like the classic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that at the moment the task function (`function(cb) { ... }`) is called, `search` already has a different value, the value of the last iteration. All the tasks refer to the same `search` variable and therefore perform the same search.

This is the typical "closure inside loop" problem.

You need to create scope per iteration. See [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) for solutions.

Comment: Could you give a little example on how this would be coded?

Comment: There are so many examples in the linked question. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19324832/218196 .

Comment: Code's working great now, very quick solution. Lesson learned. Closures and scopes.

Answer (score 0):

you are not clearing Searches...

so every itteration go like:

1. add a search to searches
2. run all searches (write to log)

1st itteration: 1st search.

2nd itteration: 1st search + 2nd search.

3rd itteration: 1st search + 2nd search + 3rd search.

you might wanted to run the `async.parallel()` after the while ends.